# Notifications using firebase for android studio

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm making an app that requires to book people for a specific purpose. I would like to notify the person that he is being booked by someone. I can't figure out how this is done. 
Examples of sending notifications from the server to everyone who has the app is available but that is not what i want.
Once someone clicks the book button from his account, the other person should get a notification. Please help!

Comment: You can use GCM

Comment: You need a server with some custom logic

Comment: On Clicking the Button you can call your API, from there you can get something. Whatever you are getting, show those in Notification.

Comment: sent a post request to firebase server when book button is clicked and then use token of other device to sent notification through server.

Comment: This is a rather broad description. Translating it into working code is beyond the scope of StackOverflow. But wee https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html for a simple way to notify users through Firebase Cloud Messaging topics.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below steps for achieve this same.

**Step 1:** Need to store token from "FirebaseInstanceId" when user signup or signin and also store that token on web server.

**Step 2:** Need web-service where we can send that "Book" button selected user **userId** through web-service. After that web-service working on that request, find TOKEN from server of that same user and set notification payload with

{ to: "token", ... }

and then send notification with some intial details using FCM.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Create account in FCM

**Step 2 :** Create app in FCM Console

**step 3 :** Get Token id of device and send to server.